# How can I debug variables by console which bind to the controller by controllerAs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, console

Usually when I´m working with Controllers, I bind the data I need to the `$scope` to access them from the markup. But when I use `controllerAs` the data should be attached to `"this"` in the controller.

So `"this.foo = 'bar'"` instead of `"$scope.foo = 'bar'"`

But how can I debug the data then from the browser with the developer console? Normally I have my `"AngularJS Batarang"` plugin and I can print everything which is part of the current scope but I don´t know how to print the data which are bind to the controller.

Comment: good old watchpoints are often overlooked, but do have the unique ability to pause/capture/report even anon data that is unreachable from the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually use `$scope` in the same way; the `controllerAs` name will be on your `$scope`.

So if the `controllerAs` is named "myController":

- Open Developer Tools
- Select "Inspect Element" for something on the page. Your console window can now access `$scope` for that element (thanks to Batarang)
- Now you can type `$scope.myController.foo` to get access to the properties.

Each time you select a different element in the DOM, the `$scope` object in the console window will reference what's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This was the right hint. I already tried that but the problem was, that i´ve tried it in the following Plunker preview (http://embed.plnkr.co/ZtuoTVgPLuMWDT2ejULW/preview) and as the content is contained in an iframe i was not able to reach the scope on the normal way.

Comment: If you don't have the Batarang extension, you can (also first "Inspect Element" on something and then) do `angular.element($0).scope().myController.foo`

Answer (score 0):

If I am following your question correctly, you can debug values bound to the controller by using:

```
 var ctrl = ele.controller();
```

This [post](https://www.ng-book.com/p/Debugging-AngularJS/) has a very useful write-up about debugging.